# Restoring PostgreSQL database without having a dump just the database files

Tags: postgresql

My hoster upgraded my Ubuntu server and it's not booting any more. The only way I can access my data any more is in read mode via a rescue environment (SSH shell).

I am running a postgres 9.1 installation on the crashed server. I am not able to start the postgres server in the rescue environment. I also do not have a dababase dump created with *pg_dump*.

However, I was able to copy the whole **/var/lib/postgresql** folder to a new machine . I installed Postgres 9.1 on this machine. Afertwards I replaced the **/var/lib/postgresql** with my old files.

When I start the postgres server, I get something like "incorrect checksum in control file".

I there any way to restore the database content **without using pg_dump** (since I don't have a current dump and I am not able to run it on the defective machine).

Comment: These two posts ([Re: incorrect checksum in control file](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/3499.1373168359%40sss.pgh.pa.us), and [Trying to recover a Postgres database](https://nelsonslog.wordpress.com/2012/02/05/trying-to-recover-a-postgres-database/)) seem to suggest the problem has to do with 32-bit vs 64-bit binaries.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed it was an issue between 32bit and 64bit. I had another old server running on 32bit Ubuntu. Initially I tried to restore the data on a 64bit machine. With the 32bit machine it simply worked by copying the postgres **main** directory. Finally I was able to log into the database and create a dump.